# When to use "has lived" vs. "lived" vs. "had lived"

Tags: verbs, tenses, present-perfect

> Jim has lived there.
>
> Jim lived there.
>
> Jim had lived there.

Are there any differences?
When do I use one or the other?
I'm trying to teach this to a foreign person and am having a hard time.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

- *Jim has lived there* is [present perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect). This describes a past action or event with present consequences
- *Jim lived there* is simple past or [preterite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preterite). This describes an action or event which  took place in the past
- *Jim had lived there* is past perfect or [pluperfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluperfect). This describes an action or event which took place before another past action or event.
- *Jim was living there* is past continuous or [imperfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperfect). This describes an action or event over a period of time, or coincident with or interrupted by another.
- *Jim had been living there* is past perfect continuous. This describes an action or event over a period of time which took place before another past action or event.

So you might have something like the following (true) statements.

> Jim was living in South Africa when his fourth child was born.
>
> Jim had been living in Pakistan before he moved to the United States.
>
> Jim lived in Malaysia for three years in the 1960s.
>
> Jim did not live in France, but he did live in Switzerland near the French border.
>
> Jim has lived in England since his retirement and does not want to move house ever again.

Comment: (+1) An excellent answer! Great examples. Consider adding for present perfect a 'since' example, to show that this tense/aspect can continue up to the present. 'Jim has lived in Geneva since he moved there after his parents' divorce', for example.

Comment: @Karl: I have changed the list slightly to meet your point, as in real life the parents of the Jim I am thinking of did not divorce.

Comment: Fair enough. Well incorporated.

Comment: +1. Quick question: why using (Jim had been living in) and not (Jim had lived in)?

Comment: @Joraid: It seemed to fit better, but the alternative is not wrong.  In fact several of the alternatives fit in the Pakistan before US example, with the continuous versions suggesting a more immediate move from one country to the next.

Comment: By the way, Jim died in 2013 aged 93.

Answer (score 3):

> Jim has lived there.

At some time in the past, that was Jim's residence, possibly more than once, but we're probably talking about a short duration and may be talking about a recent period of time.

> Jim lived there.

At one time that was Jim's home. We might have started the conversation talking about a house, but now we're mentioning that Jim used to live in it. Or we could be talking about Jim and where he lived. He probably lived in that place for a longer period of time.

> Jim had lived there.

We might be confirming that Jim did once live in that place at some point in the past, or we could be talking about a certain period of time in the past (call it 2005) where Jim was living in a certain place and wanted to specify that at some previous time (call it 2000) Jim was living at a different place. We might also be introducing the topic of where Jim was living at a certain time in order to contrast it with some other place or contradict someone's assertion that Jim did not ever live there.

Comment: You might add that *has* necessarily suggests that Jim's living there (in the past) has an effect on the present (ie. there is evidence that he has lived here).