# When to use "I was ... " and when "I had been ... "?

Tags: grammar, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

I guess it's about simple past vs. past perfect usage but some examples are welcomed, I'm really not sure if I understand it correctly.

EDIT: Right, probably I should be more specific. The thing is currently I'm reading one (american) book where, of course, a narration style dominates. And yet, the main protagonist often changes a tense from "I was" to "I had been" and I simply can't figure out the rule.

Comment: [tutorials on past vs past perfect](http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/pastpf.htm) are likely to be of help here in providing examples.

Comment: I don't think this question is on topic here. Why don't you read up on the tenses a bit and ask any specific questions you have here? For example, "rule x says y, and yet example z seems to contradict this; how come?".

Comment: Related: [When to use “has lived” vs. “lived” vs. “had lived”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19471/when-to-use-has-lived-vs-lived-vs-had-lived). See also our general reference: [How do the tenses in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another/21847#21847)

Comment: OK, I've been paying more attention while reading the book and realized there's really nothing strange going on. Flagged to remove as it's really not a good question. My apologies.

Comment: You can visit the English and Literary Department of the University of Nigeria via http://unn.edu.ng/department/english-and-literary-studies for answers to this question.

Answer (score 3):

To me, "had been" implies a change of state:

- The phone rang. I was asleep. (No implication of state change. Further sentences would clarify if the speaker woke up, or never heard it.)
- The phone rang. I had been asleep. (But I after it rang, I wasn't asleep any more.)

Answer (score 1):

The past perfect, or *pluperfect*, is used to introduce a past event that took place before another past event:

> I had worked as a bricklayer for five years before I was promoted.

To indicate that an event took place in the past without relating it to another event, you would use the simple past tense.

> I worked as a bricklayer for five years.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Joe McMahon.  Allow me to don my technical writing hat.  Using "weak" grammar is one of my pet peeves!

Don't use past and future tense out of context, when making a statement.  Using direct words makes a strong, clear statement.  The following examples have no punctuation, to emphasize grammar.  The first of the paired sentences is weak and milk-toast -- the second is the Chuck Norris version.

> - I just wanted to ask if you could correct your spelling.
> - I want you to correct your spelling.

This sentence sounds awkward:

> - I had been walking when I was asked for spare change.
> - I was walking when asked for spare change.