# Present perfect continuous for finished actions

Tags: grammar

Since present perfect continuous is used to talk about an activity that has finished, but whose results are visible now, can I use it for an action like these two ones;

'I have been living in Los Angeles.'

'I have been living in Los Angeles my whole life.'

Meaning that both actions are   finished actions, as I have relocated recently to another location and the result of my relocation is obvious.

If present perfect continuous doesn't show that these two actions above are finished actions, then in what cases does present perfect continuous express that the action has finished?

Thanks

Comment: 'have been' is not a finished action.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do the tenses in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use “has lived” vs. “lived” vs. “had lived”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19471/when-to-use-has-lived-vs-lived-vs-had-lived)

Comment: @Matt: I don't think so. The chart in the answer to your first link effectively says *present perfect continuous applies up to some point just before "the present"*, which I think is not generally the case. And I see no reference to present perfect continuous anywhere in the second link - all it has is **past** perfect continuous.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yeah, I got confused between "Jim had been living there" and "Jim has been living there"

Comment: @Matt: To be honest, I'm not sure those tense choices necessarily say anything at all about whether Jim *still* lives there. Suppose Jim is an octogenarian vegetarian. I can say *"Jim has been avoiding meat since he was ten"*. Or indeed, *"By the time he left school, Jim had been avoiding meat for many years"*.

Answer (score 9):

Present perfect continuous, aka [present perfect **progressive**](http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/present-perfect-progressive) *- expresses an action that recently stopped or is still going on. It puts emphasis on the duration or course of the action.*

Although it doesn't necessarily imply the action has *finished*, it very specifically contextualises the "duration or course" of that action relative to *the present moment*. Often, to indicate that the action has been continuous right up until [about] now, and has either just ended or will end very shortly.

In fact, unless the context or specific verb suggests otherwise, it more commonly implies that the action is still ongoing. Thus for example *"I have been living there for years"* normally implies you're *still* living there at the time of speaking.

But we often use this construction when the action has *just* finished - for example, when answering the telephone you might say *"I've [I have] been waiting for you to call"*. In practice this means exactly the same as *"I'd [I **had**] been waiting for you to call"*, since the context clearly implies you're *no longer* waiting.

Sometimes we use it simply to stress continuous action from past through present and on into the future - *"I have been doing this all my life, and I'm not going to stop now"*.

Present perfect continuous *(I **have** been doing sth)* can be used whether or not you're still doing it, whereas past perfect continuous *(I **had** been doing sth)* always implies you're no longer doing it.

Comment: It's clear to me that  in your example ( "I've [I have] been waiting for you to call") and in an example like this one; My hands are dirty, because I have been gardening.  present perfect continuous implies that both actions have finished, but it's not clear to me if I can use it in these two sentences;  'I have been living in Los Angeles.'

'I have been living in Los Angeles my whole life.'
to mean that these two actions have finished too.

Comment: @Monica: I don't think there's *any* context where you can say *"I have been living in Los Angeles my whole life"* if you're not still living there. Per my third paragraph, the default meaning of the tense is that it's *still ongoing*. To convey that you no longer live there, you'd have to say *"I had been living..."*, or *"I lived..."*

Comment: ...as for *"...because I have been gardening"*, it's just the context that suggests "completed action". I can quite validly say *"My rich aunt has been supporting me through my first year at college, and will continue doing this next year - but she says I will have to pay my own way for the final year"*. Don't be fixated on the idea that this tense automatically implies the action is finished at time of speaking - that simply isn't true.

Comment: ... *"I'm bored because I've been sitting here in this chair with no-one to talk to for hours"* certainly doesn't imply you've actually got up out of your chair.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanations. I understand now.

Comment: What about these comments? Are they right? I have been driving my car.(I am still driving it)

I have been driving my car for ages/for five years.(I am still driving it)

I have driven my car.(He/she doesn't drive it anymore)

I have driven my car for ages/for five years.(The person may or may not be driving it anymore)

They have been married.(They are not married anymore)

They have been married for twenty years/for ages(They may or may not be married anymore)

Thanks

Comment: Does  'I have been driving my car'  mean that I have been driving my car recently, but I am not driving it at the moment? Can it mean anything else?

Comment: @Monica: Per my second comment above, in and of itself, present perfect continuous doesn't really indicate anything about whether the action is still ongoing or not - all it does is make "the present moment" important (you've *just* stopped, or are just about to stop, or are *still* doing it).

Comment: "My rich aunt has been supporting me through my first year at college, and will continue doing this next year..." - in which year does the saying of the sentence take place?

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Does 'I have been driving my car' mean that I have been driving my car recently, but I am not driving it at the moment? Can it mean anything else?

Yes, it can mean something else. It can mean the car is still being driven. Imagine two people in a car, one person is driving and they have been travelling for an hour.

> Passenger: Why haven't you fed the cat in the last hour?
>
> Driver: (Because) I have been driving my car!!

But this would be more natural if the person said simply "*[Because] I have been driving!*".

Answer (score 0):

"My rich aunt has been supporting me through my first year at college, and will continue doing this next year..." - in which year does the saying of the sentence take place?

In the person's first year at college. (The first year has not finished yet).
We know this because 'next year' must mean the second year, not the third...

Comment: What has this got to do with the question?

Comment: It's present perfect continuous. He wanted to know if the action is finished or not.